# Why is CPP Check not showing any ERRORS?

Tags: c++, xml, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

This

```
cppcheck --enable=style --inconclusive --check-config --xml --xml-version=2 -v -I.. -I../mocks -I../gmock -I../gtest -DUNIT_TEST ../src
```

results in this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results version="2">
  <cppcheck version="1.52"/>
  <errors>
Checking ../src/AppMain.cpp...
  </errors>
</results>
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong - but what?

Btw, I am certain that the code has problems, but just to be sure, I pasted these two lines into it

```
 char a[10];
 a[10] = 0;
```

And there was no report of referencing out of bounds

Comment: I think it could be useful for you to try out PVS-Studio. It is as simple as CppCheck in usage. I have pasted these two strings and the analyzer gave me such a message: [V557](http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0148/) Array overrun is possible. The '10' index is pointing beyond array bound.

Comment: Thanks for teh tip )+1), however CPPcheck is the mandated tool around here and I also need it to work with Jenkins. Plus, I doubt that the company would pay for a toll (which doesn't even list its prices - you have to give them contact details), when we already use a good (the most popular), free one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without a minimal working example to reproduce the problem it is hard to help.

First of all, remove the check-config parameter since it [does the following](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/cppcheck.1.html):

> --check-config       Check cppcheck configuration. The normal code
> analysis is disabled by this flag.

If you define UNIT_TEST and this particular snippet is not active because of this, it won't show any problems.

Furthermore, you should specify "--enable=all" if you want to see errors because out-of-bounds is classified as error, not as style. Unused variable (as given in your example) is a style problem though.

Running cppcheck (v1.72)

```
cppcheck --enable=all --inconclusive --xml-version=2 -v foo.cpp
```

on this

```
void main()
{
  char a[10];
  a[10] = 0;
}
```

results in the following output for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results version="2">
    <cppcheck version="1.72"/>
    <errors>
        <error id="unreadVariable" severity="style" msg="Variable &apos;a&apos; is assigned a value that is never used." verbose="Variable &apos;a&apos; is assigned a value that is never used.">
            <location file="foo.cpp" line="5"/>
        </error>
        <error id="arrayIndexOutOfBounds" severity="error" msg="Array &apos;a[10]&apos; accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds." verbose="Array &apos;a[10]&apos; accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds.">
            <location file="foo.cpp" line="5"/>
        </error>
    </errors>
</results>
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be undocumented, but [it exists](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp#L245). The cli also mentions it, at least on a more current version.

Comment: i should not have linked against master, the highlighted line moved of course. Check [this](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/361ae311f6ec4b6f7be7c70c9d9aa7eb5344fd22/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp#L257) to see what i meant in the comment above